# Can I replace bookmark with bookmark,bak in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Today, suddenly I lost most of my bookmark bar bookmarks.
I tried to import from an older xml file, but it only imports one bookmark??? (I looked in the file, there are thousands).

I found a 'bookmark' file in the Chrome user data, dated today and only 593kb.
Next to it there is a 2 days old filr called bookmarks.bak that is 1.47MB.

Can I change name to the .bak file and get chrome to use it?

Comment: that is no harm for trying to rename the .bak first, you can try first

Comment: Here you go: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/chrome/deleted$20bookmarks/chrome/JCP5QtmMyZE